# ReCAPTCHA Ajax API Image customisation?

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, ajax, recaptcha

I am aware that it is possible to manipulate the ReCAPTCHA image using PHP, like this: http://www.phpcaptcha.org/documentation/customizing-securimage/

I am using the AJAX API for generating and validating my captcha image, and was wondering if it is possible to do similar or the same with AJAX.
I don't think it's a part of the API, but perhaps the request could run past my server, generate some parameters, then grab the image from ReCAPTCHA, then return it all via AJAX.

For the sake of including code:

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {
    //Create ReCaptcha
    var options = { 
        target: '#output',    
        beforeSubmit: showRequest,   
        success: showResponse,  
        url: 'recaptcha/recaptcha.php' 
    }; 
    $('#registerform').submit(function() { 
        $(this).ajaxSubmit(options); 
        return false; 
    });
    var RecaptchaOptions = {
        theme : 'custom'
    };
    Recaptcha.create('PUBLIC_KEY', 'recaptcha_image', RecaptchaOptions);
});
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to easy use [reCaptcha](http://www.google.com/recaptcha) simply with AJAX:

read [this nice article here](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display) about displaying it especially the [AJAX Part](https://developers.google.com/recaptcha/docs/display#AJAX) and the [DEMO](http://www.google.com/recaptcha/demo/ajax)

Hope this helps you to solve your problem :)

Comment: I had already read that, not exactly what I am looking to do, [here's what my captcha looks like at the moment](http://i.imm.io/kxcl.png). What I was hoping to achieve is to reduce it it one word, rather than the default two.

Comment: This is nothing I can read out of your question. I do also not know if this is possible. Besides that fact I would not prefer that! Why changing a system which is well known and accepted on many websites? If you solve that problem, where is your additional benefit in having such a thing?